# Share static class in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have multiples classes in my program.
At the beguinning, i initiate a static class that contains an SQLite connexion :

```
class Utils :

dbClient = None

@staticmethod
def initialize(settings):
    from storage.sqlite.SQLiteClient import SqliteClient
    Utils.dbClient = SqliteClient(settings)
```

then my app.py start the class by calling the initilize static method.

```
Utils.initialize(settings)
```

app.py call 2 others classes in multiprocessing mode. I would like these 2 classes using the same connexion (from Utils).

```
Utils.dbClient.insert(...)
```

How to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt that a connection can be passed to a subprocess.

Comment: really ? may be with class inheritance ?

Comment: Class inheritance is about the static structure of your code. Passing an open SQLite connection to a subprocess has nothing to do with the static structure.

Comment: A network socket is generally bound to a single process - you cannot easily share a socket between multiple processes, and you probably shouldn't. Why do you think you want/need to do this? If you really need to, you could consider using threading.